# Oracle SQL Extracting CSV frim from a CLOB and loading into a table

Tags: oracle, csv

Im using Oracle Database XE 11g. I have a routine based on the Alexandria utilities - 
https://code.google.com/p/plsql-utils/

it extracts a CSV file from a Clob (first using Blob_to_clob)  and allows it to be read as a table with columns, to extract the data and load it into a table.

The problem, is that its slow, and seems to be quite CPU intensive. 20,000 records takes over 8 minutes.. Ive asked on the forum, and generally, but can't seem to find alternative faster way to extract a CSV file from a CLOB and load into a table.

The CSV file is standard comma delimited, new line format...

Anyone any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Looks like the `clob_to_csv` routine does a lot of dbms_lob.instr and dbms_lob.substr. It would be much much faster if it read the data in large chunks and parsed them as varchar2. I don't have time to work on it right now though but it would be a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

let the database read the csv, addressed as an external table, or use sqlldr to load the csv to a table.